# Telethon's download_media method doesn't work in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I try to download the image files of the messages from Telegram channels using Telethon in my lambda_handler:

```
with TelegramClient(StringSession(string_session), api_id=int(telegram_id), api_hash=telegram_hash) as client:
    count = 1
    for message in client.iter_messages(name, limit=limit, reverse=False):
        news.append(message.text)
                
        file_name = f"{str(count)}"
        message.download_media(file=f"/tmp/{file_name}")
                
        path = f"/tmp/{file_name}"
        key = None
                
        s3.upload_file(Filename=path, Bucket='telebotmedia', Key=file_name)
        count += 1
```

but I get this error:

`[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'photo_2024-01-16_17-34-40.jpg'`

I am using **AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole** and **PowerUserAccess** policies in my function role. But I couldn't achieve to download it inside the `tmp` directory.

Comment: The `Read-only file system` message normally appears with AWS Lambda functions when code attempts to save a file outside of the `/tmp/` directory. I see that you have coded this path into the `download_media()` call, but it appears not to be working as expected. I suggest hard-coding a value there as a test (`message.download_media(file=f"/tmp/foo")` just to verify that this is the problem. You could also try writing a file to that location _not_ using Telethon to check that it works, such as: `open('/tmp/test.txt', w)`

Comment: I cannot download anything manually either. Don't know why. Looks like the main issue here is that im not able to access to ```/tmp``` folder in any way.